# How to make background color transition from dark red to green?

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to get a countdown timer (already have that part figured out) transition from dark red to light green in a matter of 5 seconds.

Comment: Show your code. You likely just need to use variables for your color RGB values, and then modify those variables over time.

Comment: I had code however it started from green not red but I input the red colour, so I decided to scrap it.

Comment: If you can supply that code as part of your question someone may be able to help

Comment: you have to specify how that transition should look like. is it linear?

Answer (score 0):

Colors can be represented by a combination of 3 values, each ranging from 0-255. These values represent a color's RGB value. The first number represents "how much" red is in the color, second for green, and the third for blue.

Here are some examples of RGB colors,

- Pure Red = (255, 0, 0)
- Pure Green = (0, 255, 0)
- Pure Blue = (0, 0, 255)
- Black = (0, 0, 0)
- White = (255, 255, 255)
- Dark Magenta = (100, 0, 100)
- Cyan = (0, 200, 200)
- Yellow = (255, 255, 0)

You can construct a color in Roblox by using a [Color3](https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/datatype/Color3). There is a constructor to easily convert an RGB color into a Color3 with `Color3.fromRGB(number r, number g, number b)`. So if you want to get from Dark Red (50, 0, 0) to Bright Green (100, 255, 100) over 5 seconds you can use `Color3:lerp(Color3 targetColor, number alpha)`.

```
local startingColor = Color3.fromRGB(50, 0, 0) -- dark red
local targetColor = Color3.fromRGB(100, 255, 100) -- bright green

local testBrick = Instance.new("Part", game.workspace)
testBrick.Color = startingColor

-- make a loop to change the color, lerp() expects a number between 0 - 1.
local timeToComplete = 5.0 -- seconds
local framesPerSecond = 60.0
local waitAmt = 1.0 / framesPerSecond
local stepAmt = 1.0 / (timeToComplete * framesPerSecond)
local i = 0.0

while (i < 1.0)
    testBrick.Color = startingColor:lerp(targetColor, i)
    i = i + stepAmt
    wait(waitAmt)
end

-- by now the color should be close to the target color, ensure it is done
testBrick.Color = targetColor
```

Under the hood, this is just doing some simple linear algebra to convert the 3 values from the starting point to the end. Hope this helps.